# Safe pagination without a rowlock

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, pagination

I'm working with SQL Server and Entity Framework. I need to fetch a large number of records and process them.

I'm afraid of "out-of-memory" or other performance problems, so I want to implement the fetching and processing in batches. The problem is that between each fetch, the underlying data in the database might change, resulting in omitting elements (a record is removed, then next offset is applied to the select operation but the data in the database has 'moved to the left' and the first item of the next page is omitted).

This is important because the purpose of the select is not just presentation but further processing.

I thought about setting the transaction's isolation level to repeatable read to avoid changes coming from other users, but the processing takes a lot of time and that would lock the changes to the table for the whole time.

I also thought about paginating using the key rather than the offset (SQL where/limit). This way no data that was initially in the db could be omitted, only the changes that happen after the pagination has started could be omitted or not. However the user is informed about the number of items to be processed in the beginning of the process. And this number might not be correct, but we only learn about it in the end of the long process.

What would your advice be? Am I missing something?

Comment: You could use `SNAPSHOT` isolation in a transaction (requires the `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` database option turned on). I would avoid long-running transactions, though. Consider a caching layer for the snapshot and paganation.

Comment: What is the nature of the data and, related, the table? I ask because it may be appropriate to go with a `select top(1000) ... where ID > @ID order by ID` method which shouldn't fall prey to the phenomenon you describe like a fetch/offset method does.

Comment: @BenThul it's possible, I mentioned it in the second to last paragraph, but I was hoping to get also other ideas, as this approach would require a modification to the current system where the user initially knows how many records will be processed. In this approach we learn the real number of records at the end of the process

Comment: Ah... I missed that. That said, there have been so many problems in my career that would have been fixed with UI treatment saying that counts are approximate. That is, how important is it that a) the UI says "there are 561,423" records and b) that if they get to the end of the set via paging that it turns out that there were 561,427 records? Only you can answer that, but my opinion in these matters historically has been "it doesn't matter at all".

Comment: Also note that you can enumerate over a query result without loading all the entities at once.  Just `foreach (var e in db.Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.whatver = 'something)) ...`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft if I dont load all entities at once does it mean that the internal state of the data is mutable while the foreach loop is executing? Is there like a snapshot at that point? Sorry for my ignorance in this topic

Comment: If you've got the database option READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT on, which is the default for EF Code-First and Azure SQL Database, and is a best-practice for all new projects, then you get statement-level snapshot semantics.  So you will read the table as it was at the point-in-time when your query started.  If you don't have this option set you can opt in to snapshot semantics by using the SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level.